# Utilising JSON values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, json

I'm originally a PHP programmer and have been struggling with this for at least 2 whole 9-to-5 days now. I've come a long way but I seem to have gotten stuck trying to figure out the last bit. It SHOULD be fairly simple, but somehow I can't seem to find anything that coulp help me figure it out.

I have the folliwing jQuery code that returns some values from the PHP backend:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "KMS-backend.php",
  data: "&checkdivpage=" + pagename,
  success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
  }
})
```

This successfully alerts the returned JSON data:

```
[{
  "divid": "col-whole"
}, {
  "divid": "col-halfleft"
}]
```

...Now what I can't seem to figure out, is how to turn this JSON object into an array, so I can loop the returned values! I can't even figure out how to return the first value seperately. Every answer I can find explains you can return each individual result with `data[0]`, `data[1]`, `data[2]` etc, like with a normal array, but this just returns the character in that position!

How can I return these values so that I can loop each of them seperately?

Comment: Are we sure it's being evaluated as a JSON response and not plain text?  What happens if you use the getJSON call instead or you `eval` (for testing) the results?

Comment: Have you tried specifying `dataType: "json"` as an option to `.ajax()` yet?

Comment: I tried eval(data) before, yes... That returns `[object Object],[object Object]`. ---- So weird, when I try specifying the dataType it returns the same, even without `eval()`. What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set dataType

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "KMS-backend.php",
    data: "&checkdivpage="+pagename ,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data[0].divid);
    }
```

Comment: My GOD, that did it!!! At last! Thank you so much for the feedback guys, all 3 of your guesses were spot-on. You just saved me a headache, and with that, probably my computer and window glass :)

THANK YOU!